# Limit of a function with two variables.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> I was asked to calculate the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}
> \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^2+sin^2(x^3)}.$$

**My attempt:**

I want to use the Squeezing Principle.

$$\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^2+1} \le \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^2+sin^2(x^3)} \le \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^2}$$

I know that the RHS $\to$ $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ by the [Sertöz Theorem](http://sertoz.bilkent.edu.tr/depo/sertoz_theorem.htm). But, I could not calculate the LHS. Could you give a hint to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 \le  |x^2\frac{y^2}{x^4+y^2+1}| \le |x^2|\to 0$